# Error: Expected a “;” Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h
#define compare(x,y) (((x)<(y)) ? -1 : ((X)==(y))?0:1)
int binsearch(int[], int, int, int);
int main(void)
{
    int aaa[6] = { 1, 5, 5, 10, 11, 21 };

    int binsearch(int list[], int searchnum, int left, int right)
    {
```

> The "{" is undelined with the mistake:
>       Error: Expected a “;”

```
int middle;


        while (left <= right)
        {
            middle = left = (left + right) / 2;
            switch (compare(list[middle], searchnum))
            {
            case -1: left = middle + 1;
                break;
            case 0:
                return middle;
            case 1: right = middle - 1;

            }

        }
        return -1;

    }

    if (binsearch(aaa[], 10, 0, 6) == 10)
    {
        printf(" %d ", middle);
    }
    else
    {
        printf(" %d ", binsearch);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

could you help me?
 what's the problem? that is full-code.
i think i missed something but i cannot realize. or is that problem of visual studio2013?

Comment: There are not nested functions in C (at least not without extensions)

Comment: You've omitted the closing `>` of `#include <math.h>`.

Comment: Move the `int binsearch(...)` function outside of `main`

Comment: i find problem... really thank you